Is there a way to increase the recapcha active time or have it remain active once the verification is done?
I have a form, I use recapcha v2 but let's say I send a large document and this causes my ajax request to take a while and I made a loader but after a while the recapcha is deactivated and if the form is sent like this I get an error that the recapcha does not is checked, is there any way to solve it?
I have only investigated but I can't find anything even in the google documentation
